# 2010s-20s TV show where someone lands in the middle of nowhere but the person looking for them finds them

Tags: story-identification, tv

My partner admits that it sounds a bit like she's trying to describe a dream, but she would be thrilled if anyone has a lead on this TV show:

- People were excited about it when it was coming out.
- This was around the pandemic, so it may have been released 2019-2022.
- Her memory of this show was triggered by our watching *Good Omens*, but it wasn't a funny show.
- We watched one episode, and at the end of this episode, someome landed or arrived in the middle of nowhere, and got caught by the person they were trying to run from.
- It was dark outside at this point.

I am drawing a thousand blanks, but she'd be very grateful for your assistance...

Comment: This does feel very spare of details... does your partner remember the gender, race, nationality of either character?

Answer (score 4):

Since  you mentioned *Good Omens*, could this have been *[American Gods](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1898069/)*, which is based on the book of the same name by [Neil Gaiman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Gaiman).

The first season was released on [Starz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starz) in 2017, with season 2 in 2019 and season 3 in 2021. Following release on Starz, episodes were available on Amazon Video. The series has had critical acclaim, and given Gaiman's popularity and [seeming involvement in the development of the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods_(TV_series)#Development), I would not doubt that it was highly anticipated.

The story starts with the main character, Shadow Moon, who has recently been released from prison to attend his wife's funeral after she died in a car crash. The funeral is to be held in a small (I think mid-west USA) town. repeatedly refusing job offers from a mysterious man called Mr Wednesday who keeps appearing in places where Shadow is headed, despite the locations not being on any normal tourist or common travel routes.

There is a lot of dark imagery in the first few episodes, but I don't recall it being dark at the point of Shadow accepting the offer from Mr Wednesday, but certainly dim.

There is very little humour in the book and the couple of episodes I have watched, though some black humour prevails, as it does in much of Neil Gaiman's work.